# Error in blinking led using GPIO_12 of ESP32

Tags: touch, esp32, gpio, arduino-esp32, touchpad

Here is my code:

```
#define LED_BUILTIN 12

// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() 
{
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() 
{
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);// turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
}
```

The above code works perfectly fine for GPIO_2 but fails for GPIO_12. I want to ask whether it is giving fault because I am using touchpad pin or there is some other error?

I have attached an LED to GPIO_12 of ESP32 and after program uploading, my led is not blinking. I have tried to connect voltmeter to GPIO_12 and it is giving 0.5 volts with minor fluctuation. I was expecting a change of voltage after each second as per HIGH/LOW conditions of my code but unfortunately, I am not getting the desired result. What could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 0):

Now I have found out the solution so let's share so that others can also get benefit. The code for which I was following the reference website contained 36 pins which mean 18 pins on each side but in my version of the board there were total 30 pins on my board which mean 15 pins on each side. Now that I have got pin out reference of that board and my board also, everything is fine, aligned and makes perfect sense. Problem was that the hardware which the reference website referred to had different hardware version with 36 pins and my hardware contained 30 total pins and was a different version of ESP32.